# iCloud documents too large file

Tags: swift, realm, icloud

i'm using iCloud documents in my app, when i move a local realm file to documents directory of iCloud i obtain this error:

```
default.realm, NSUnderlyingError=0x11f9b90e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=34 \"Result too large\"
```

If i try with a little file, all works fine. The file it's about 30mb, and i have 50GB of free space on my iCloud, whats wrong? where is the problem?

Many apps i have installed saves files bigger then mine, for example whatsapp store more then 300mb, i see this data in iCloud settings

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying the file, or actually moving it? It's not recommended to move Realm files after they've been opened for the first time since the Realm framework can't cope with that.

If you're exporting a copy, it's recommended to export a copy using `realm.writeCopy(toPath:)` since this will clean out and compress the new Realm file, making it much smaller. :)